# How does FilePathResult work?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, download

We are developing a Site for a client who is hosting their own site and file share. The site can be accessed externally from there network, it can additionally be accessed internally via an internal domain. The site uses a fileshare for upload and download of documents. This fileshare is not externally visible.

[image: Crude Network Diagram]

When a user downloads a file from the Website we want to know what actually happens. If we serve a FilePathResponse to the user using an internal filepath it currently works (one that we can't navigate to from our office). This would suggest that the File is always doing a trip from the fileshare, to the webserver and finally to the client via the internet. What I would want is for this File to be just given directly to the User if they can access the file internally. Can anyone shed any light on what is happening?

Comment: are you worried about firewall issues, DMZ issues , etc... do you have a system or network admin..? sounds like you're setting yourself up for some real potential issues and or vulnerabilities ....FileShares have access rights etc.. how are you planning to manage who can and can not have access to your site.. sounds like you need to do a little bit more investigating or hire someone who's familiar with what it is your're trying to do.. sounds like a bad idea if I am understanding this correctly

Comment: Hi, the network isn't being run by me or my company but entirely by the company we're doing the work for. They are just questioning how that transfer is done purely for speed. The reason being if it is a direct link to a file then they will get the internal network speed, otherwise it would transfer over the internet. Given that these files can be several gigabytes it could be an issue

Comment: sounds like you need to ask more questions on your end.. there are many ways to download / stream files of numerous sizes.. it's not as simple as running something like file.Copy..